# Contact Form Laravel 4- Troubles with routes

Tags: php, laravel-4

I am trying to do this contact form, but I am :(

### I have this form:

```
{{ Form::open(array('url' => 'PagesController@contact', 'method' => 'POST',  'role' =>'form', 'class' =>'form-horizontal' )) }}
    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('name', 'Nombre:', ['class' => '']) }}                       
        {{ Form::text('name', '', ['class' => 'form-control', 'maxlength' => 20]) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('email', 'Email:', ['class' => '']) }}                   
        {{ Form::email('email', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('subject', 'Asunto:', ['class' => '']) }}                    
        {{ Form::text('subject', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>
        <div class="form-group">    
        {{ Form::label('country', 'Pais:', ['class' => '']) }}                  
        {{ Form::text('country', '', ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::label('textarea', 'Message:', ['class' => '']) }}                          
        {{ Form::textarea('msg', '',  ['class' => 'form-control', 'placeholder' =>'Your Message', 'required'=>'true'])  }}
    </div>


    <div class="form-group">
        {{ Form::submit('Send', array('class' => 'btn btn-primary btn-md')) }}
    </div>


{{ Form::close() }}
```

### In view/emails/contact.blade.php

```
Name:   {{ $name }}
Email:  {{ $email }}
Country:    {{ $country }}
Subject:    {{ $subject }}
Message: {{ $msg }
```

### In my App/Config/mail.php:

```
return array(   
   'driver' = 'smtp',  
   'host' = 'smtp.gmail.com',  
   'port' = 587,  <br/> 
   'from' = array('address' = 'africamia@gmail.com', 'name' = 'Admin'),  
   'encryption' = 'tls',   
   'username' = 'africamia@gmail.com',   
   'password' = '123456',   
   'sendmail' =  '/usr/sbin/sendmail -bs',   
   'pretend' = false,  
);
```

### In my Pages@Controller.php

```
public function contact()
{
    $validation = New ?? I don't know what I do here :(;

    if($validation->passes()) {

       $fromEmail = Input::get('email');
       $fromName = Input::get('name');
       $subject = "Email from someone at website.com";
       $data = [ 'msg' => Input::get('message') ];

       $toEmail = 'africamia83@gmail.com';
       $toName = 'Admin';

       Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) use ($toEmail, $toName, $fromEmail, $fromName, $subject){

           $message->to($toEmail, $toName);

           $message->from($fromEmail, $fromName);

           $message->subject($subject);
       });

    return Redirect::to('/gracias')
        ->with('message', 'Your message was successfully sent!');
    }

    return Redirect::back()
        ->withInput()
        ->withErrors($validation->errors);
}
```

### In Routes

```
Route::get('contact', array('as' =>'contact', 'uses'=> 'PagesController@contact'));

Route::get('contact', function() {

return View::make('contact');

});
```

### I have this error:

When I click n Submit Button, in the browser appears: ../public/PagesController@contact

Error in exception handler: Route [/] not defined for PagesController@contact

Comment: Try to replace `'url' => 'PagesController@contact'` with `'action' => 'PagesController@contact'`

Comment: You define `Route::get('contact')...` twice in your routes.php. You need to define what happens when the form is POSTed: `Route::post('contact')...`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit a for ,it is a `POST` request, not `GET`. You define that as a `GET` request. Please change the route file as below:

`Route::post('contact', 'PagesController@contact');`

Comment: Thank u so much for your support.Im with Laravel Doc, it is hard. I create a: `function contact(){`
    `$validation = new Services\Validators\Contact;`    I add a folder in App/Validator/contact.php with:  `<?php namespace pp\Extension\Validation;`
 `use Illuminate\Validation\Validator;`
 `class CustomValidation extends Validator{`
   `public function alpha_spaces($attribute, $value, $parameters) {`
    `if(preg_match("/^([-a-z0-9_ ])+$/i", $value)){`
      `return true;
   }
   return false;`
  }
 }`   and I have: **Class 'Services\Validators\Contact' not found**

Comment: better you make request file for validation.To do that open your terminal and type :`php artisan make:request Contact`.